# Где лучше определить параметры проекта (Laravel 5.3)?

Tags: архитектура, laravel5

У проекта есть параметры, которые должны быть доступными везде.

При этом важно, чтоб они были в отдельном файле (есть несколько сайтов с общими базами данных и одинаковым кодом - отличаются только эти параметры).

Вот какие варианты приходят на ум:

1. Сделать отдельный файл с определением констант и инклудить его в routes/web.php
2. Сделать отдельный файл с параметрами и инклудить его в config/app.php
3. Как выяснилось, можно просто кинуть файл с константами к категорию config - он сам как-то проинклудится.

Помогите выбрать или предложите что-то поумней!